# How to get gmail inbox feed OAuth 2.0 Playground, connecting with C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm doing some tests with google's OAuth 2.0 Playground, with the API https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom, to read the rss feeds through a C # .net page. At the playground I generated the Authorization code, Refresh token, Access token and also created a project and generated client ID and client secret. Could someone help me in C # .net, connect, authorize, use refresh, so that in my application that already reads other feeds I can point to the URL: https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom and have access to rss feeds.

Thank you

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: I dont no how to use in C # .net Authorization code, Refresh token, Access token connect to the gmail inbox feed api that is working via Google's OAuth 2.0 Playground. The code to do that.

Comment: You need to learn the things which you don't know. I am sorry to say that you will not get your work done here. You need to make an attempt and write code and if you face issues in that you can ask questions here with proper details.

Comment: Google search of Google Authorization code c# returns [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implementing-oauth2-0-authorization-for-google-in-asp-net/) and [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) and many other results

Comment: yes, i already researched it, but most of the codes are old. Do not use Refresh token, Access token.
On the playground with Refresh token, Access token works great, I am not finding it in C # .net how to do to works automatically and without expiring